# Ways to access firebase storage (photos) via web app

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm confused as to the appropriate way to access a bunch of images stored in Firebase storage with a react redux firebase web app. In short, I'd love to get a walkthrough of, once a photo has been uploaded to firebase storage, how you'd go about linking it to a firebase db (like what exactly from the snapshot returned you'd store), then access it (if it's not just `<img src={data.downloadURL} />`), and also how you'd handle (if necessary) updating that link when the photo gets overwritten. *If you can answer that, feel free to skip the rest of this...*

Two options I came across are either

1. store the full URL in my firebase DB, or
2. store something less, like the path within the bucket, then call downloadURL() for every photo... which seems like a lot of unnecessary traffic, no?

My db structure at the moment is like so:

```
{
  <someProjectId>:  {
    imgs: {
      <someAutoGenId>: {
        "name":"photo1.jpg",
        "url":"https://<bucket, path, etc>token=<token>"
      },
      ...
    },
    <otherProjectDetails>: "",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Going forward with that structure and the first idea listed, I ran into trouble when a photo was overwritten, so I would need to go through the list of images and remove the db record that matches the name (or find it and update its URL). I could do this (at most, there would be two refs with the old token that I would need to replace), but then I saw people doing it via option 2, though not necessarily with my exact situation.

*The last thing I did see a few times, were similar questions with generic responses pointing to Cloud Functions, which I will look into right after posting, but I wasn't sure if that was overcomplicating things in my case, so I figured it couldn't hurt too much to ask. I initially saw/read about Cloud Functions and the fact that Firebase's db is "live," but wasn't sure if that played well in a React/Redux environment. Regardless, I'd appreciate any insight, and thank you.*

Comment: I forgot to mention a third option I'm currently thinking about which would be to allow unrestricted read access to the firebase storage bucket, then omit the token when saving the url to the database. Keeping the "alt" variable (set equal to "media") at the end, I am able to get the picture to render, and then there's nothing to update in the database when images get overwritten.

For now, this is a working solution for me, but I'm going to try to figure out a solution involving Cloud Functions, as that seems to be the go-to answer for similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In researching Cloud Functions, I realized that the use of Cloud Functions wasn't an entirely separate option, but rather a way to accomplish the first option I listed above (and probably the second as well). I really tried to make this clear, but I'm pretty confident I failed... so my apologies. Here's my (2-Part) working solution to syncing references in Firebase DB to Firebase Storage urls (in a React Redux Web App, though I think Part One should be applicable regardless):

**PART ONE**

Follow along here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started to get cloud functions enabled.

The part of my database with the info I was storing relating to the images was at `/projects/detail/{projectKey}/imgs` and had this structure:

`{ 
  <autoGenKey1>: {
    name: 'image1.jpg',
    url: <longURLWithToken>
  },
  <moreAutoGenKeys>: {
    ...
  }, ...}`

My cloud function looked like this:

```js
exports.updateURLToken = functions.database.ref(`/projects/detail/{projectKey}/imgs`)
  .onWrite(event => {

    const projectKey = event.params.projectKey
    const newObjectSet = event.data.val()
      const newKeys = Object.keys(newObjectSet)
    const oldObjectSet = event.data.previous.val()
      const oldKeys = Object.keys(oldObjectSet)
    let newObjectKey = null

    // If something was removed, none of this is necessary - return
    if (oldKeys.length > newKeys.length) {
      return null
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < newKeys.length; ++i) {// Looking for the new object -> will be missing in oldObjectSet
      const key = newKeys[i]
      if (oldKeys.indexOf(key) === -1) {// Found new object
        newObjectKey = key
        break
      }
    }

    if (newObjectKey !== null) {// Checking if new object overwrote an existing object (same name)
      const newObject = newObjectSet[newObjectKey]
      let duplicateKey = null
      for (let i = 0; i < oldKeys.length; ++i) {
        const oldObject = oldObjectSet[oldKeys[i]]
        if (newObject.name === oldObject.name) {// Duplicate found
          duplicateKey = oldKeys[i]
          break
        }
      }

      if (duplicateKey !== null) {// Remove duplicate
        return event.data.ref.child(duplicateKey).remove((error) => error ? 'Error removing duplicate project detail image' : true)
      }
    }

    return null
  })
```

After loading this function, it would run every time anything changed at that location (`projects/detail/{projectKey}/imgs`). So I uploaded the images, added a new object to my db with the name and url, then this would find the new object that was created, and if it had a duplicate name, that old object with the same name was removed from the db.

**PART TWO**

So now my database had the correct info, but unless I refreshed the page after every time images were uploaded, adding the new object to my database resulted (locally) in me having all the duplicate refs still, and this is where the realtime database came in to play.

Inside my container, I have:

```js
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  syncProjectDetailImages(dispatch) // the relavant line -> imported from api.js
  return bindActionCreators({
    ...projectsContentActionCreators,
    ...themeActionCreators,
    ...userActionCreators,
  }, dispatch)
}
```

Then my api.js holds that syncProjectDetailImages function:

```js
const SAVING_PROJECT_SUCCESS = 'SAVING_PROJECT_SUCCESS'
export function syncProjectDetailImages (dispatch) {
  ref.child(`projects/detail`).on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
    dispatch(projectDetailImagesUpdated(snapshot.key, snapshot.val()))
  })
}
function projectDetailImagesUpdated (key, updatedProject) {
  return {
    type: SAVING_PROJECT_SUCCESS,
    group: 'detail',
    key,
    updatedProject
  }
}
```

And finally, dispatch is figured out in my modules folder (I used the same function I would when saving any part of an updated project with redux - no new code was necessary)