# How to allow access to photos for your web app in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I authorise my app to be able to access images in my firebase storage without the user having to sign in?
Should I just remove all read protections in the security rules for images, or is there a better way to do this altogether?

For context this is so that the app can load images on the home page that have been uploaded by other users for non authorised users to browse. Like the airbnb homepage for example.

Or is there some way to authorise my app on its own? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can follow this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571334/ways-to-access-firebase-storage-photos-via-web-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to provide public access to files stored in Firebase Storage to a web applications, you can request a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for each file.  Download URLs are fully public until you choose to revoke their access token.  No SDK is needed to access these files - the URL is all you need.